# Site is not styling <p> content

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, styling

I think something is over riding the styling of my text but im not too sure what it is. In my code i have "#column-right" and "#column-right h1" and it is styling correctly. Now im trying to style the paragraphs text. I have "#full_width" and "#full_width p" however i cant get the p to style correctly. What is the problem with my code that is causing this issue?

**UPDATE:**

It should look like this: [Screenshot 1](http://i46.tinypic.com/5yupw7.png)

It looks like this: [Screenshot 2](http://i47.tinypic.com/2s9xix1.png)

*INB4: I will be pulling the style out into an external sheet after the build is done.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

/** -------------------------------MAIN - DON'T EDIT---------------------------------- **/

html {
max-width:56em;
margin:0 auto;
padding:1.25em;
font:100% "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
color:#222;
background:#e2e7e8;
}

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.clear { 
clear:both; 
}



/** ---------------------------HEADER COLUMN LEFT------------------------------------- **/

#headermanager {
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #1c1c1c;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #1c1c1c;
box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #1c1c1c;
}

#column-left {
width: 230px;
float: left;
padding-top:20px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}


.pic {
 border: 10px solid #fff;  
 float: left;
 height: 180px;
 width: 180px;
 overflow: hidden;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #111;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #111;  
}

.morphimg {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.morphimg:hover {
border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg);          
}

/** -------------------------------HEADER COLUMN CENTER------------------------------- **/


#column-center {
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
width: 316px;
float: left;
padding-top:20px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

/** ---------------------------------HEADER COLUMN RIGHT------------------------------ **/


#column-right {

text-align:right;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
width: 310px;
float:right;
padding-top:20px;
padding-right:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

#column-right h1 {

font-size:3em;
font-weight:200;
text-align:right;
width: 310px;
float:right;
}   

#column-right h2 {

font-size:1.3em;
font-weight:100;
text-align:right;
width: 310px;
float:right;
}   

#column-right h3 {

font-size:0.9em;
font-weight:200;
text-align:right;
width: 310px;
float:right;
} 


#progress_bar {
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
width: 310px;
}

/** -----------------------------------SECTION HEADERS-------------------------------- **/

#section_header {
background: #e94939;
padding: 1rem;  
}

#section_header h1 {
font-size: 0.65em;
font-weight: 500;
letter-spacing: 0.35em;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: white;
text-align: center;

/** ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- **/
/** -------------------------------------TEXT LAYOUTS--------------------------------- **/
/** ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- **/

/** --------------------------------------ABOUT ME------------------------------------ **/

#full_width{    
padding-left:7.8em;
padding-right:7.8em;
padding-top:2.85em;
padding-bottom:2.85em;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

#full_width p { 
text-align:left;
font-size:0.8em;
font-weight:200;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>

<!--***********************************************************************************-->    
<!--********************************* HEADER STARTS ***********************************-->    
<!--***********************************************************************************-->    


<!----------------------------------COLUMN LEFT STARTS----------------------------------->    
    <div id="column-left">
        <div class="morphimg pic">
            <img src="http://i50.tinypic.com/11r4nwh.png" alt="beach">
        </div>
    </div>

 <!------------------------------- COLUMN CENTER STARTS ---------------------------------->

<div id="column-center">Social Hover</div>

<!----------------------------------COLUMN RIGHT STARTS---------------------------------->  
 <div id="headermanager">
<div id="column-right">
    <h1>John Doe</h1>
        <h2>lipsium ordium consecultar</h2>
            <h3>www.jdoedesign.com<br>
            me@jdoedesign.com<br>
            256-220-8360<br>
            141 Ritter Street Huntsville, AL 35816</h3>
    </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>


<div id="section_header">
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>


<div id="full_width">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dui
        lorem, dictum non varius eget, accumsan ut tellus. Mauris sed nunc
        vitae lectus egestas aliquam eu eu libero. Cras tempus euismod
        interdum. Aenean rutrum orci nec mauris venenatis eu blandit est
        eleifend. Cras elit magna, tempus eu luctus quis, dapibus et purus.
        Suspendisse et quam ut est interdum porta. Morbi sed rhoncus risus.
        Pellentesque eu libero justo, at varius purus. Duis faucibus ultrices
        ipsum vitae eleifend. Suspendisse viverra congue dolor faucibus
        feugiat. Etiam pulvinar congue tellus sit amet dapibus. Morbi et
        ultricies diam. Suspendisse id vehicula lacus. Integer quis risus diam,
        a facilisis justo.<br><br>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
        faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed lobortis
        aliquet lorem, at placerat orci fermentum non. Nam ut tortor eu eros
        gravida semper. Cras eget est ante. Sed vehicula justo et urna lacinia
        volutpat. Vestibulum dolor ante, sollicitudin vel ultricies nec, mattis
        non urna. Donec eget lorem ligula, quis ornare odio</p>
</div>

<!--***********************************************************************************-->    
<!--******************************** ABOUT ME STARTS **********************************-->    
<!--***********************************************************************************-->      



<!--***********************************************************************************-->    
<!--***************************** WORK EXPERIENCE STARTS ******************************-->    
<!--***********************************************************************************-->



<!--***********************************************************************************-->    
<!--******************************** EDUCATION STARTS *********************************-->    
<!--***********************************************************************************-->  



<!--***********************************************************************************-->    
<!--***************************** TECHNICAL SKILLS STARTS *****************************-->    
<!--***********************************************************************************-->



<!--***********************************************************************************-->    
<!--********************************** AWARDS STARTS **********************************-->    
<!--***********************************************************************************-->  



<!--***********************************************************************************-->    
<!--********************************** CONTACT STARTS *********************************-->    
<!--***********************************************************************************-->      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use your browser's DOM inspector to look at the applied & overridden CSS rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot your closing `}`

```
#section_header h1 {
  font-size: 0.65em;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.35em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
/* } Was not placed */
```

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnSTn/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `#section_header h1` selector is missing its closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following selector for specificity:

```
#full_width > p {
 /*myStyles*/
}
```

With this, you will select all paragraphs inside the full_width div.

Comment: That didn't do anything

Comment: @LastBreath - I'd downvote that comment if I could, use of the !important tag should be an absolute last resort. Reduce specificity of winning rules if these are difficult to override and it this isn't needed, understand the cascade order and if necessary increase the specificity in rules that are not being applied. Work with the CSS specificity and cascade and not against them - what do you do when everything is "!important"?